# Layer Load Order

Tags: leaflet

It seems like the layers are loading from ground up. Is there any way to change the layer load order ?
I have a foreground layer that I want to load up in the first place, I just don't know how.
Thanks!

Comment: I've tried changing the zIndex parameter which didn't help

Comment: I mean, I've (sort of) discovered that layers are loaded the way they are added. So I've added the layers and modified the zindex after (to keep their order but change their depth) - this didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's true. Although there's a zIndex parameter it doesn't seem to work for much...

Comment: Any suggestions as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing: `yourLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);` to change the zindex of a layer.

Regards